# как получить protected свойство в PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

при использвании wp_remote_get приходит такой ответ:

```
array(6) {
 ["headers"]=>
 object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#502 (1) {
["data":protected]=>
array(7) {
  ["server"]=>
  string(5) "nginx"
  ["date"]=>
  string(29) "Wed, 02 Jun 2021 14:13:23 GMT"
  ["content-type"]=>
  string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  ["vary"]=>
  string(15) "Accept-Encoding"
  ["x-powered-by"]=>
  string(10) "PHP/7.3.28"
  ["link"]=>
  string(77) "<http://loftaparthotel.construct.ru/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/""
  ["content-encoding"]=>
  string(4) "gzip"
   }
 }
 ["body"]=>
 string(21572) "
```

Вопрос: как вытащить защищенное свойство data['date']

Comment: Открыть исходный код и увидеть что класс поддерживает `[]`-нотацию: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests_utility_caseinsensitivedictionary/

Comment: открыл и увидел - а дальше?

Comment: и так видно, что это массив, только к элементам массива доступа нет (protected), даже с помощью рефлексии

Comment: вытащил все, что хотел